# C++ error when compiling file

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors

I have a class called BottlingPlant.
I created the following headerfile:

```
#ifndef __BOTTLINGPLANT_H__
#define __BOTTLINGPLANT_H__

#include <iostream>

class BottlingPlant {
public:
BottlingPlant( Printer &prt, NameServer &nameServer, unsigned int numVendingMachines, unsigned int maxShippedPerFlavour, unsigned int maxStockPerFlavour, unsigned int timeBetweenShipments );
void getShipment( unsigned int cargo[ ] );
void action();  
};

#endif
```

And the following .cc file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PRNG.h"
#include "bottlingplant.h"

BottlingPlant::BottlingPlant( Printer &prt, NameServer &nameServer, unsigned int numVendingMachines, unsigned int maxShippedPerFlavour, unsigned int maxStockPerFlavour, unsigned int timeBetweenShipments ) {


}

void BottlingPlant::getShipment( unsigned int cargo[ ] ) {

}

void BottlingPlant::action() {

}
```

When I try compiling the .cc, it gives me an error in the .cc and .h at the line:

```
BottlingPlant::BottlingPlant( Printer &prt, NameServer &nameServer, unsigned int numVendingMachines, unsigned int maxShippedPerFlavour, unsigned int maxStockPerFlavour, unsigned int timeBetweenShipments )
```

Saying that there is an expected `)` before the `&` token. This doesn't make any sense to me as there is no open `(`. I'm just not sure why it's giving this error. `Printer` and `NameServer` are just separate classes a part of the project but.. do I need to include their header files as well or no?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Avoid starting identifiers with double underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter. Those are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Yes, you need the header files for Printer and Nameserver in this current implementation.

Comment: About your problem, each file should include what it needs and nothing more. In `BottlingPlant`, `Printer` etc. hasn't been included yet, and you shouldn't count on a different file coming first.

Comment: AHH, that is what was wrong. Thank you all for your prompt replies. I will fix this right now. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the header files for any classes you're using, even classes in the same project.  The compiler processes each individual source file as a separate [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29), and it won't know that a class exists if the header that defines it hasn't been included in that translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Your .h file should include the headers which have the class definitions for Printer and NameServer. As an example if they're in MyHeader.h, the following example shown should fix those errors.

```
#ifndef __BOTTLINGPLANT_H__
#define __BOTTLINGPLANT_H__

#include <iostream>
#include "MyHeader.h"

class BottlingPlant {
public:
BottlingPlant( Printer &prt, NameServer &nameServer, unsigned int numVendingMachines, unsigned int maxShippedPerFlavour, unsigned int maxStockPerFlavour, unsigned int timeBetweenShipments );
void getShipment( unsigned int cargo[ ] );
void action();  
};

#endif
```